# Error No such file or directory mac terminal

Tags: macos

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm 100% beginner and I have zero ideas how to fix this on macOS Terminal.

Someone please walk me through the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix it by adding these lines to ~/.bash_profile.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You will need to start a new bash session to load those changes.